# Variance of sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, expectation

I am trying to show that:

$$\mathbb{V}[X+Y] = \mathbb{V}[X]+2\text{Cov}[XY]+\mathbb{V}[Y]$$

We have that:

$$\mathbb{V}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2]-\mathbb{E}[X+Y]^2$$

From the definition of covariance:

$$\text{Cov}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X]]\mathbb{E}[Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]]$$

First question: How come the above makes any sense at all? i.e. we know that expectation is idempotent, so: $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X]]=\mathbb{E}[X]$, this mans that $\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X]] = \mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[X]=0$...

I proceed to expand the second line of maths:

$$\mathbb{V}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] + 2\mathbb{E}[XY]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2] -(\mathbb{E}[X]^2 + 2\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]+\mathbb{E}[Y]^2)$$

Second question: How does $\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X]]\mathbb{E}[Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]] = \mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$?

Comment: Your definition of covariance is wrong. It's not $E[X-E(X)]E[Y-E(Y)]$ but $Cov(X,Y)=E[(X-E(X))\times (Y-E(Y))]$ which is also equal to $E(XY)-E(X)\times E(Y)$.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the definition of covariance:
>
> > $$\text{Cov}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X]]\mathbb{E}[Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]]$$
>
> First question: How come the above makes any sense at all? i.e. we know that expectation is idempotent, so: $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X]]=\mathbb{E}[X]$, this mans that $\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X]] = \mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[X]=0$...
>
> Second question: How does $\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X]]\mathbb{E}[Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]] = \mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$?

It doesn't because you have the definition wrong.  It an expectation of a product not the product of expectations

$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Cov}[XY] = & ~ \mathsf{E}\big[(X-\mathsf{E}[X])(Y-\mathsf{E}[Y])\big]
\\ = & ~ \mathsf E\big(XY-X~\mathsf E(Y)-\mathsf E(X)~Y+\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(Y)\big)
\\ = & ~ \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X~\mathsf E(Y))-\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X)~Y)+\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(Y))
\\ = & ~ \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(Y)-\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(Y)+\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(Y)
\\ = & ~ \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(Y)
\end{align}$$